# Count occurrences of item in one dataframe in another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am currently running into a problem and hoping that someone could assist. Currently have 2 dataframes of items which are hundreds of thousands of lines long. (one has over 200k and one over 180k). the larger of the 2 dataframes is going to contain unique values of users, while the smaller one does not so for example:

```
df1:
user1
user2
user3
user4
user5

df2:
user1
user1
user5
user4
user5
user5
```

What i need to do is take each user from df1 and efficiently see if it is in df2 and how many times it occurs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `value_counts`

```
df1['Newcount']=df1['df1:'].map(df2['df2:'].value_counts())
df1
Out[117]: 
    df1:  Newcount
0  user1       2.0
1  user2       NaN
2  user3       NaN
3  user4       1.0
4  user5       3.0
```

Comment: Good solution :)

Comment: @piRSquared thank you sir : -) Both of your guys comment mean a lot to me :-)

Comment: Thank you! This did exactly what I wanted!!

Comment: @Wen How would you do this if you're looking for a value greater than or equal to? so for example in this data set I also have dates, I want anything from df2 that is after the date in df1

Comment: @SamL you can try `merge_asof`

Comment: Actually I stated that wrong.. So i want to see if the userid is equal in both and if the date is the same (I've already removed the time stamp) and then add the count.. 

Sorry i'm kind of new to python and esp pandas.. trying to learn as i can.

Comment: same like you can using `merge`, include date with the userid as the key

Comment: @SamL also , I suggested open a new question , since the question is totally different from the current one

Answer (score 3):

Use `pd.factorize` and `np.bincount` to efficiently produce the value counts

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df2.user)
d = dict(zip(u, np.bincount(f)))

df1['Counts'] = df1.user.map(d)
df1

    user  Counts
0  user1     2.0
1  user2     NaN
2  user3     NaN
3  user4     1.0
4  user5     3.0
```

---

### Setup

```
df1 = pd.Series(list('12345')).radd('user').to_frame('user')
df2 = pd.Series(list('115455')).radd('user').to_frame('user')
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the relevant column in each DataFrame is called `'user'`, you can use

```
pd.merge(
    df1,
    df2.user.groupby(df2.user).count(),
    left_on='user',
    right_index=True,
    how='left')
```

Explanation:

- The `groupby` + `count` will find the number of occurrences of each user. It will create a DataFrame whose index is the user, and the value is the count.
- The merge left-merges the resulting DataFrame onto `df1`.

Comment: `df1.join(df2.user.groupby(df2.user).count().rename('Count'), on='user')`